# How to add autocomplete tag in Webforms module

Tags: 8, webforms

According to the accessibility guidelines fields like email or name need to have an autocomplete tag like, autocomplete=on.

I found the option to turn autocomplete on and off in webforms in the field settings and form settings. But these do not add the tag. If I add it manually in the YAML option then it does appear. But I want writers to be able to enabled this option themselves. Is this possible in webforms?

I'm trying to achieve the result in the image. Webforms allows me to turn it off and on, but only with off does the tag appear. With on it doesn't.

https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Techniques/html/H98

[image: Autocomplete example]

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! :-) Everything is possible. But you probably should provide a little bit more information. As not everybody know that much about your accessibility guidelines and what exactly is supposed to happen here in the markup or anywhere else. Also about making this a configurable option we need to know how you think this should be configured at what place exactly from which user? Please update your question accordingly. Many thanks!

Comment: It looks like you found a bug/issue with the Webform module. Please create a ticket in the Webform module's issue queue. https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/webform?status=All&version=8.x